# Gradle Copy Task causes file permission issue

Tags: linux, gradle, permissions

## Background

I have a JetBrains Plugin that I am developing. Recently, I moved from a `Windows` to a `Ubuntu` system. I am trying to set up everything correctly as before. **Note**: I am fairly new to Linux.

## Issue

I am having an apparent file permission issue (as can be seen in the `error` section of this question) when I ran the following `Gradle` script. **Note**: Whenever I build the project, this Gradle script is automatically called. It also worked correctly on Windows.

If I comment out the `copy{...}` closure then everything works correctly. *I just need to manually copy over the required file.*

```
tasks.create(name: "copyJar_v${project['version']}") {

    group GROUP_CHROMATERIAL

    def mostCurrentJarFile = "ChroMATERIAL-${project['version']}.jar"

    // comment this out and there are not errors, but I need to do this copy manually
    copy {
        into '/'    // Copy into project's root folder
        from 'build/libs', {
            include mostCurrentJarFile
            rename mostCurrentJarFile, 'ChroMATERIAL.jar'
        }
    }

}
```

#### Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 
  '/home/ciscorucinski/IdeaProjects/ChroMATERIAL/ChroMATERIAL/build.gradle' line: 100

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':ChroMATERIAL'.
> Could not copy file '/home/ciscorucinski/IdeaProjects/ChroMATERIAL/ChroMATERIAL/build/libs/ChroMATERIAL-2.5.1.jar' to '/ChroMATERIAL.jar'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.139 secs
/ChroMATERIAL.jar (Permission denied)
오후 12:20:39: Task execution finished 'copyJar_v2.5.1'.
```

## What I tried

I have been using the UI to modify the file permissions of the Plugin Project Folder within `IdeaProjects`.

1. I gave everyone `Create and delete files` permissions and I `Change Permissions for Enclosing Files...`
2. Everyone has `Read and write` access to files and `Create and delete files` access to folders.
3. Clicked `Change`
4. Run the Gradle script again ... same error message

#### Thoughts

- It appears that Linux is not letting Gradle modify these files. I can comment out the code and do everything myself, but I need to allow Gradle to have higher control. Don't know how though.
- I notice that when I go back to `Change Permissions for Enclosing Files...` the shown permissions are not what I selected! `Others` has `Read-only` access to files and `Access files` access to folders. I don't know if this is common Ubuntu behavior, a bug, or something else.

  - It would be nice to know how to give as restrictive as possible access while fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is true -- you cannot (and should not) copy files into the Root folder in a linux box. You could if you ran the script as `sudo`, but that is a bad idea.

**Edited**

Since you want to copy to the root of the project, you can use ${projectDir} or ${rootDir}.

Also, you should be able to do this without the hassle of a closure -- and it makes your script cleaner, IMHO -- by using the built in Copy task:

```
task copyClientLoc(type: Copy) {                  
    from "build/libs/"
    into "${rootDir}"
    include "ChroMATERIAL-${project['version']}.jar"
    fileMode = 0644
}
```

Comment: My task name is set up to be dynamic. As a secondary precaution that I am copying the right version. I thought that I cannot us the built-in Copy task. Am I wrong?

Comment: On `Windows`, `into '/'` means the root folder of the project. What you are saying is that `into '/'` on Linux means the root folder in Linux?? That doesn't seem right!? Seems like huge incompatibility issues

Comment: In Linux, / is the root folder of the system -- equivalent to "C:\" in Windows.
In Gradle, the root folder of the project is given by ${projectDir}, or ${rootDir} for multi-project builds.

Comment: Edited to copy the file to the root directory for the project. This is the directory where the ```build.gradle``` file is located.

Comment: Why does your task name need to be dynamic? That would make it nigh impossible to use as a dependency of some other task?

Comment: `finalizedBy "copyJar_v${project['version']}"` is how I have implemented dependencies with dynamic naming ^^